# Migrating Android app from SQLiteOpenHelper to Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

I am trying to migrate my app's database from `SQLiteOpenHelper` to `RoomDatabase`, but since my project is huge I want to do that incrementally, without breaking everything (because the database is used everywhere). My database has 3 tables: `files`, `sharedFiles` and `unuploadedFiles`, I want to migrate only `unuploadedFiles` to use the Room

**I have two questions**:

- Can this actually work? Can I have both the SQLiteOpenHelper and RoomDatabase working together with the same database?
- My current database version is 8, when I migrate to Room, should my migration be from 8 to 9 or from 1 to 2?

Here is some code:

What I have a dbHelper class, which does the requests to the database

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 8;
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FilesDatabase";

  private static final String TABLE_FILES = "files";
  private static final String TABLE_SHARED = "sharedfiles";
  private static final String TABLE_UNUPLOADED = "unuploadedfiles";

  ...

}
```

now I added the FilesDatabase which implements RoomDatabase

```
@Database(entities = [(UnuploadedFile::class)], version = 2)
abstract class FilesDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun unuploadedFileDao(): UnuploadedFileDao

    companion object {

        private val MIGRATION_1_2: Migration = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            }
        }

        @Volatile
        @JvmStatic
        private var INSTANCE: FilesDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): FilesDatabase =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: buildDatabase(context).also { INSTANCE = it }
            }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                FilesDatabase::class.java, "FilesDatabase.db")
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                .build()
    }
}
```

and my LocalFilesDataSource is what holds the UnuploadedFileDao and the old dbHelper

```
class LocalFilesDataSource(context: Context,
                           private val unuploadedFileDao: UnuploadedFileDao) : FilesDataSource {

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: LocalFilesDataSource? = null

        @JvmStatic
        fun getInstance(context: Context, unuploadedFileDao: UnuploadedFileDao): LocalFilesDataSource {
            val result = INSTANCE ?: LocalFilesDataSource(context, unuploadedFileDao)
            INSTANCE = result
            return result
        }
    }

    private val dbHelper: DBHelper = DBHelper(context)
    ...
}
```

and now when I want to make requests to the unuploadedFiles table, I call the UnuploadedFilesDao methods:

```
override fun addUnuploadedFile(userName: String, fileName: String) {
    unuploadedFileDao.insertUnuploadedFile(UnuploadedFile(userName, fileName))
}
```

and when I want to make requests to the other tables, I call the dbHelper:

```
override fun insertFile(path: String?, filename: String?, serverModifiedDate: Date?, localModDate: Date?): Long =
    dbHelper.insertFile(path, filename, serverModifiedDate, localModDate)
```

Comment: "Can I have both the SQLiteOpenHelper and RoomDatabase working together with the same database?" -- I would not recommend it. They each have their own connection to the database, and that can cause problems. This is why we migrated to having singleton `SQLiteOpenHelper` instances in the first place. "since my project is huge" -- you only have three tables. There should be only 1-3 classes that touch those tables. If you have more than that, first refactor your code to minimize the number of classes that work directly with the tables.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are right, only 1-3 classes should touch the database, but this is old, inherited project and it's really messed up, so I cannot simply refactor it, that's why I'm trying to do the migration safely. But probably you are right that instead of migrating to room, I must refactor what I currently have.